# Cannot edit images inside sitecore field renderer

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have used Sitecore field renderer for one of my page to be edited in the Sitecore page editor. That page includes an image which needs to be reference from Sitecore media library.

So I insert the image control into the markup of the Sitecore field renderer as follows

```
<img id="imgBusinessAdFeatues" class="classifiedImageSamples" src="~/media/Images/What is a Business Account/businessAdFeatures.ashx" alt="Business Ad with Features" />
```

“~/media/Images/What is a Business Account/businessAdFeatures.ashx” is the path to the image that stored in Sitecore media folder.

Now the image is rendered properly inside the page, but when I tried to edit that image (upload a new image) using Sitecore page editor it’s not allow me.

Is there any way to make the image editable (Upload a new image) when I open that page in Sitecore page editor?

Thanks

---

Thank you for the ideas.

But my problem is little bit different. I have Sitecore field renderer in in my sample page.

```
<sc:FieldRenderer ID="frTestPage" runat="server" />
```

From the code behind on that page, I bind a Sitecore item as follows.

```
frTestPage.Item = DatabaseManager.MasterDatabase.GetItem(“itemID1”);
frTestPage.FieldName = "Content";
```

In the item that I’m binding to the field renderer, it has richtextbox field name “Content”.

Within that “Content” field I have inserted my markup to be render to the page. So that markup consist of following img tag and other relevant HTML.

```
<img id="imgBusinessAdFeatues" class="classifiedImageSamples" src="~/media/Images/What is a Business Account/businessAdFeatures.ashx" alt="Business Ad with Features" />
```

So how can I give the image src path correctly which reference to an image in Sitecore media library.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong to use hardcoded path for images: 
You can see all parameters [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XSL/5%203%20Enhancements/Image%20Enhancements.aspx).

If you use XSLT to render your images, you can apply the parameters on the `sc:image` directly:

```xml
<sc:image field="MyImage" width="150" height="100" bc="ffffff"/>
```

If you use UserControls (.ascx) to render your images, you can register the following tagprefix to access `sc:Image` and `sc:FieldRenderer`:

```xml
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sc" Namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Edit(Page Editor), then More -> Insert Image, see:

[image]

Also, to have a more edit options you can use "Edit e related Item"